# Remote desktop only working when console is attached in vmware

Tags: vmware-esxi, remote-desktop, windows-10

New install of windows10 on vmware esxi (6.5).

Remote desktop enabled and working.

When idle for some hours remote-desktop can't connect to the windows machine. However, when opening a console to the windows machine inside the web-ui for vmware, remote-desktop starts working again. It seems like a windows/remote-desktop issue ("if I poke it it starts working again"), but what can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: This sounds like a power plan/configuration issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check windows 10 power plan ? It's sound like window goes hibernate.

Comment: So far so good :) if it still works when i get back home i'll mark this as the solution.